# Want to change the frame Name from Excel to ETABS via API

Tags: excel, vba

My API calls are failing

```
Public Sub ETABS_MODEL_BeamAnnotation_ChangeUniqueNames()

    Dim Name As String
    Dim NewName As String
    'Dim frameobj As cFrameObj

   'create ETABS object
        Dim myHelper As cHelper
        Set myHelper = New Helper
        Set EtabsObject = myHelper.GetObject("CSI.ETABS.API.ETABSObject")

        
    ' Get a reference to the active model
       Set SapModel = EtabsObject.SapModel
       
       'Set frameobj = SapModel.frameobj
       
    'set as active instance
       ret = EtabsObject.SetAsActiveObject
       
        
    'Check if ETABS object was successfully obtained
        If EtabsObject Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Could not get reference to ETABS. Please make sure ETABS is open.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        
    ' Clear previous data in Sheet "Beams"

        Dim AllFramesSheet As Worksheet
        Set AllFramesSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AllFrames")
        
        
     ' Clear all data in Sheet "Beams" from row 7 onwards
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = AllFramesSheet.Cells(AllFramesSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
    ' Loop through the rows in "AllFrames" sheet and change the names in ETABS
        For i = 7 To lastRow
            Name = AllFramesSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value ' GET Names of all frames
            Debug.Print "Name(" & i & ") : " & Name
            NewName = AllFramesSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value ' Get New Names of all frames
            Debug.Print "NewName(" & i & ") : " & NewName
    
            ' Call the ChangeName function
            ret = SapModel.frameobj.ChangeName(Name, NewName)
            
            ' Check if the name change was successful
            If ret <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "Failed to change name for row " & i & ". Error code: " & ret, vbExclamation
            End If
        Next i
        
End Sub
```

I am getting message:

> "Failed to change name for row"

in a loop meaning my API calls are failing.